# Как настроить подсветку sql запросов в phpstorm?

Tags: php, mysql

Собственно вопрос, как настроить подсветку sql  функций в шторме ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить `Database` компонент на ваш коннекшн:

> **View**
>   -> **Tools Windows**
>   -> **Database**
>   -> **Add**
>   -> **DataSource**
>   -> **Mysql**

Настраиваете параметры подключения к базе

Не забываем скачать **Driver** для MySQL

Проверить c помощью кнопки **Test Connection**

Если все ок, то во вкладке **Schemas** отметить схемы с которыми будете работать.

Ну и подождать пока подгрузится структура базы

**P.S.** После изменений в структуру, нужно рефрешнуть ее, а то оно в кеш складывает

Answer (score 0):

File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Sql dialects > правая колонка